# Function causes mysql_close() to leave connection thread open

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, database-connection

The function below, was found responsible for causing a huge connection leak, as each thread that passed the conn as a parameter got the connection undetachable.

All queries work as expected, just `mysql_close()` function doesn't stop the connection thread anymore.

This function worked fine and I don't remember changing anything since it last worked. Just changed project where it was used and some compiler flags.

I've read in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-close.html) that :

> **mysql_close()** deallocates the connection handle pointed to by mysql if the handle
>   was allocated automatically by mysql_init() or mysql_connect().

but didn't understand, and don't know how to test.

```
int mysql_get_item_id(MYSQL *conn, const char *item_e, const unsigned long * ip_nr, bool *is_new_item = NULL)
{
    char ip_nr_string[10];
    std::sprintf(ip_nr_string, "%lu", *ip_nr);

    string query="SELECT id FROM item_unique WHERE item='"+(string)item_e+"' LIMIT 1";
    if(mysql_real_query(conn, &query[0],query.size()))
    {
        cout<<endl<<"mysql_get_item_id -> query fail: <<"<<query<<">>"<<endl;
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));

        return 0;
    }
    else if(DEBUG_QUERY > 2)
    {
        cout<<"debug_query <<"<<query<<">>"<<endl;
    }
    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(conn);
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    if(mysql_affected_rows(conn)>0)
    {
        if( ( row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL )
        {
            if(row[0] != NULL)
            {
                long l=atoi(row[0]);
                mysql_free_result(result);
                return l;
            }
        }
    }
    // if no != NULL found

    query="INSERT IGNORE INTO item_unique(item,host_ip_nr) VALUES ('"+(string)item_e+"', '"+(string)ip_nr_string+"')";
    if(mysql_real_query(conn, &query[0],query.size()))
    {
        cout<<endl<<"mysql_get_item_id -> query fail: <<"<<query<<">>"<<endl;
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        return 0;
    }
    else if(DEBUG_QUERY > 2)
    {
        cout<<"debug_query <<"<<query<<">>"<<endl;
    }
    if(mysql_affected_rows(conn)>0)
    {
        if (is_new_item != NULL) *is_new_item=TRUE;
        return mysql_insert_id(conn);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does 'got the connection undetachable' mean? And why should mysql_close() stop a thread?

Comment: `char ip_nr[10]` is one too small for 32 bit integers.

Comment: @EJIP, I don't use a connection pool, and I create a new connection for each thread and close it at the end with `mysql_close()`. This connection I pass as argument for each function call. After calling this particular function the mysql connection thread you see with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` does not close as usual. If I comment this function out all works as expected.

Comment: @OlafDietsche , actually `char[10]` is enough to hold an **unsigned** integer, you need **11** just when you need space for the negative (`-`) sign.

Comment: You have 10 digits for a 32 bit unsigned *plus* the final NUL byte.

Comment: shouldn't the null byte be for char* and not char[] ?

Comment: You can use character arrays without a trailing NUL byte, of course. But a C string is always terminated by a NUL byte, no matter how you access it. [`sprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html) will write a terminating NUL.

Comment: I've found the problem, it seems I've missed a function that closed the thread while the connection was active... thank you all for your comments, at least I did learn something new out of it :)